# RobotFrameWork with Browser library starts in incognito modus, but the normal modus is needed

Tags: robotframework, incognito-mode

When a .robot file runs it can be started with =chromium =firefox =webkit

however it always starts in Incognito modus.

Our thought was, okay let's start is chromium and an argument
which looks like this

```
New Browser     chromium   headless=false   arg=["--profile-directory=Persoon 1"]
```

But that didn't work because everytime it starts a new session so there is no Persoon 1 so to speak.

So the essence is: how can it be run in non-incognito modus?
(and how come it starts with incognito modus, is that standard behaviour or some config issue?)

resources: https://robotframework-browser.org/

https://peter.sh/experiments/chromium-command-line/switches/

Comment: for `--profile-directory` try to use full path and avoid spaces in path or use ""

Comment: That would mke it:  New Browser  chromium  headless=false  arg=["--profile-directory=c:/space here/profile"]? or arg=["--profile-directory='c:/space here/profile'"]  ?@Juraj

Comment: still.... even if I put it in the launch.json, even if I put it in the run_robot_main__.py... incognito modus is kept all the time.

Comment: `--profile-directory="c:/space here/profile"`. did you try without a space in path (and without "")?

Answer (score 0):

The basic policy of `robotframework-browser` is to perform in `incognito` mode.

Their goal is not to leave any browser data through `incognito` mode.

Therefore, to support parts such as extension installation, `incognito` mode cannot be used. Because of that, they try to solve the problem in the following link.

https://github.com/MarketSquare/robotframework-browser/issues/963#issuecomment-913214068

However, this part has not been corrected yet.
Looks like we'll have to wait for a new version to come out.

Comment: Hey why did you get +200, I did not think this answer was worth 200 points... since when can't I decide which answer I want to give the 200 points to? wt# is this now?

Comment: @tijnn I didn't get 200 points. You don't have to decide if it doesn't make sense to you, I'm just stating the current status of what you're asking. The current state is that the person who made the library did not support the function.

Answer (score 0):

After long research the answer is:

You can't! (It's just not possible)

Browser library incognito modus is deeply baked in somewhere deep in the code.
They are working on an option to give an argument with the url so it will become possible to use the LaunchPersistent of Playwright.

Until that time this is the solution:

install SeleniumLibrary as well. For some scripts use SeleniumLibrary.
Next you use the EDGE browser with 'msedgedriver.exe'
Done! you solved the problem.

Comment: Perfect! Thank you!!!